# Given 4 points with 2 on different radius. Obtain the center of the circle.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I'm struggle on a math question that states the following:

> Black holes have an overwhelming gravity, such that the nearest stars begin spinning around them ([Example](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/483/195/original/UOJ_1783.png?1438189373)). Every affected star keeps constant angular velocity and distance from the black hole. Given 2 different positions of 2 stars in the black hole. Can you give the position of the black hole ?

Example

star 1: (12,2) , (10,8) (Respectively the old and new coordinates of the star 1)
star 2: (5,6) , (2,7) (Respectively the old and new coordinates of the star 2)

The black hole is on (2,2)

Comment: I think the points you gave were for the same time, not the same star.

Comment: What geometric relationship exists between the black hole and two positions of a particular star? (In other words: How does the center of a circle relate to two points on that circle?)

Comment: Coordinate of points corrected =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** A point $P$ is equidistant to points $A$ and $B$ if and only if it lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose the black hole is at $(x,y)$. Then the two points $(12,2)$ and $(10,8)$ must be equidistant from $(x,y)$. Write down an equation stating this fact. Similarly, $(5,6)$ and $(2,7)$ must be equidistant from $(x,y)$. Write down an equation stating this fact. Then solve that pair of equations in the two unknowns $x$ and $y$.